# couchdb4j traverse the database

Tags: java, database, couchdb

First, I'm using couchdb4j.
Normally if we want to traverse the couchdb, we put the whole database into a view by using the

ViewResults results = db.getAllDocuments()

But my database is about 1 Gb with about 110000 rows, so it is too big to put the whole database into the ViewResults List. My document id is default(that's my bad, I should have set id numbers like 1,2,3...). So, I'm just wondering is there a way to traverse the whole documents without putting them all into a view? Or, is there a way that I can export the whole database into a csv file? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> So, I'm just wondering is there a way to traverse the whole documents without putting them all into a view?

Yes. You can paginate the results of your requests by using the query parameters `?skip=...&limit=...`

You will request batches of the primary index `/_all_docs`. Every response inherits the informations you need to request the next batch. Here is an example response:

```
{
  "total_rows":12345,
  "offset":500, // the current position
  "rows" :[{...}]
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for that. but I still don't know how to do it with code. Do you know the code to traverse the couchdb? where should I set the parameters?